# Android: Instantiating Multiple Widgets From One Layout Declaration

Tags: android

I am creating a custom widget to display a rotating list of items.  I have declared the layout in `newsview.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>    
<RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/tblLink"
            style="@style/newsviewstyle"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/newsviewimg"
                style="@style/newsviewimgstyle"
                android:layout_margin="5dp" />

            <TextView 
                android:id="@+id/newsviewtitle"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@id/newsviewimg"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:textColor="#000000" />
            <TextView 
                android:id="@+id/newsviewurl"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@id/newsviewimg"
                android:layout_below="@id/newsviewtitle"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="15dp"
                android:textColor="#000000" />
        </RelativeLayout>
```

The idea is in my `main.xml`, I have a `ViewFlipper` that I would like to use animate the transitions between each item.  How could I instantiate "n" unique items declared above, so they can bee added to the `ViewFlipper`.  How would I be able to get access to the layout declared from a class outside the main activity (and also outside the package containing the main application, i.e. a view controller).

As a note,  collecting the list of items takes place in a controller outside the main activity of my application.  I would like to keep everything as much as possible in the controller for possible reuse later on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How could I instantiate "n" unique items declared above, so they can bee added to the ViewFlipper.

Use `getLayoutInflater().inflate()`, the same way you would in a custom `Adapter`. In fact, on Honeycomb, there is `AdapterViewFlipper` to handle this very scenario.

> How would I be able to get access to the layout declared from a class outside the main activity (and also outside the package containing the main application, i.e. a view controller).

I'm sorry, but this sentence did not parse for me.

Comment: Orders from on high want this targeting Android 2.1, so anything added in 3.0 is out for now.  As for the second point, I am aiming for maximum reuse of code, so the more I can pass into a controller class the better.

Comment: @Mike D: That just means you have to inflate them yourself. Not a big deal. And, as far as I am concerned, the activity (or, nowadays, the fragment) *is* the controller class.